# Find the number of solutions to this equation using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How many solutions are there to the equation
> $$x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=21$$ where each $x$ is a non negative integer such that
> $$0\le x_1 \le3 , 1 \le x_2 \lt4\text{ and }x_3\ge15$$

**My attempt:**

So I  first considered the conditions $x_1\ge0 , x_2\ge1$ and $x_3\ge15$

I found out that the total possible combinations with this restriction are $9\choose5$.
But these include do not include the other restrictions on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

So I found out the combinations for the cases of $x_1\ge4$ and $x_2\ge4$ , with an intention of subtracting these from the total combinations of $9\choose 5$.

However I am not ending up with the right answer of $106$.Could you please help me out? I used the formula of $n-r+1\choose r$

Comment: 21 can be written in 101 different ways using 5 integers, each positive and <21. This figure can be obtained using "integer partitioning" formula automated in:http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ca10ab4a89d9f0f6f378b89881f63ba3

Comment: @EmmadKareem: this problem does not deal with partitions (that is an harder problem), but just with stars and bars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, thanks for your explanation and the link.

Answer (score 6):

The problem should be equivalent to $x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5$ with $0≤x_1≤3$ and $0≤x_2<3$ and $x_3 \ge 0$.The formula should be $n+r-1\choose {r-1}$ wich gives ${9 \choose 4}=126 $ solutions without the restrictions. Applying the restrictions we need to get rid of the instances of $x_1=4$ (there are 4 of them) and $x_1=5$ (one). Also get rid of $x_2=3$ (by the formula above it is ${2+4-1 \choose 4-1}=10$) and $x_2=4 ($4 solutions$)$ and $x_2=5$ ($1$ solution). Since there is no overlap we can add all these instances and take them out of 126 to give $126-(1+4+10+1+4)=106$

Comment: How did you determine that the given problem is equivalent to the one you solved? In other words, how did you conclude that $$x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=5$$ with $0≤x_1≤3$ and $0≤x_2<3$ and $x_3 \ge 0$ is equivalent to $$x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=21$$ where each $x$ is a non negative integer such that $0\le x_1 \le3 , 1 \le x_2 \lt4\text{ and }x_3\ge15$

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic consider the bounds on $x_i$. For example, write $x_3 \mapsto x_3-15$

Answer (score 5):

The number of solutions of 
$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5= 5 $$
with the constraints $x_1\in[0,3],x_2\in[0,2]$ and $x_3,x_4,x_5\geq 0$ is given by the coefficient of $z^5$ in the product:
$$ (1+z+z^2+z^3)(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2+\ldots)(1+z+z^2+\ldots)(1+z+z^2+\ldots)$$
i.e. by the coefficient of $z^5$ in the Taylor series around $z=0$ of
$$ f(z) = \frac{(1-z^4)(1-z^3)}{(1-z)^5} = (1-z^3-z^4+z^7)\cdot\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+4}{4}z^n $$
i.e. by:
$$ \binom{5+4}{4}-\binom{2+4}{4}-\binom{1+4}{4}=\color{red}{106}.$$

Comment: Note that $1 \leq x_2 < 4$, so $x_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: noticed and fixed, thank you. My $x_2$ is the original $x_2$ minus one, so I have to take it in $[0,2]$.

Comment: And the downvote is for.... ?

Comment: Nice solution. (+1)

Comment: Why not $x_2\in [0,3]$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: because in the original problem $1\leq x_2\leq 3$, and my $x_2$ is just the original $x_2$ minus one.

Comment: Oh yeah - it's a $<$ and not a $\le$. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Student's Solutions Guide to Accompany Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, Jerrold W. Grossman, Kenneth H. Rosen, p. 222